# How do I separate my android applicationId from package name

Tags: android

Looking at [https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename?pli=1] I should be able to have separate applicationId's and a single package name. However, when I setup my build and manifest like it suggests, I am still getting the error that applicationId.R file can't be found.

I'm not sure what is going on here as I don't reference it anywhere. I only reference package.R.

Any thoughts?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...

In the intermediate manifest that is generated, the package is replaced with the applicationId. My project uses android annotations which by default looks to this to find the R file.

Android annotations allows one to set this manually in the gradle build file:

```
apt {
 arguments {
  androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
  resourcePackageName 'com.example.package.name'
 }
}
```